# How to find a faucet with a decent drain plug mechanism?

Tags: bathroom, faucet, drain

So I've replaced one bathroom faucet with a basic Delta model faucet. The problem is that the mechanism to raise and lower the plug sucks. They include a semi-hard plastic rod to connect to the rod that comes down from above the faucet to control the drain plug (I guess this is called the clevis?). But since it is plastic, when you push down on the rod, the plastic bends instead of pushing down on the lever that attaches to the drain plug. And the rod is attached to this plastic piece with only a screw (not the clevis screw) pressing into it laterally, which isn't enough force to keep the rod there, so when you pull up on the rod, it pulls out of this piece instead of raising the drain plug lever.

I just got another delta faucet and opened the box to find it has the same crappy mechanism.  I assume that the drain plug functionality isn't important enough to be spelled out on the outside of the box.

Are there better drain plug mechanisms on better faucets, or are they all like this?

Comment: In my experience, they all suck...I always just remove them and use a rubber stopper. Or get faucets without them in the first place.

Comment: "I've replaced one bathroom faucet with a basic Delta model faucet (comma) the problem is that (period)." All snarkiness aside, you should be able to get them to work after adjusting them for an hour. Usually, by the time I'm done, you have to pull it out about four inches which looks strange but it now works both ways. "Semi-hard" isn't ringing a bell (picture?), perhaps you have the compression nut too tight on the 'ball'. Does the lever operate freely when not attached to the pull rod?

Comment: I agree with Mazura, in that you may have the nut too tight.  The drain should operate with very little effort.

Comment: That was it, the nut was too tight.  Add it as an answer and I'll choose it as the answer. Thanks.